# Can I create my database design for my CMS like this?

Tags: sql, .net, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm designing a standard CMS database structure. 
These are my entities tables:

```
ServicesPage
  --ServicesPageId
  --HeaderTitle
  --HeaderParagraph
AboutPage
  --AboutPageId
  --HeaderTitle
  --HeaderParagraph
ContentColumns (A section that can belong to pages)
  --Id
  --Title
  --Paragraph
  --Image
  --FK_PageId
```

...and other pages

- ServicesPage Has Many ContentColumns
- ContentColumns Belong to only one ServicesPage
- AboutPage Has Many ContentColumns
- ContentColumns Belong to only one AboutPage

The `PageId` will hold the `Id` of the page that the content column belongs to.
So for instance AboutPage `id = 1`, `ServicesPage = 2`. Each `ContentColumn` record will have the id of the page it belongs to

I thought this would work, but I'm getting FK merge conflicts.

I really confused myself, I've done db design many times, just never a CMS. I think it's the concept that's confusing me.

It stumbled upon me that I should probably have a Pages table

```
Pages
  --PageId
  --PageName ( Don't really need this column ? )
```

The `Pages` table should have one to one `ServicesPage` and One to One `AboutPage`, and all the other pages should be in here too.

**What is wrong with how it is now vs what I came up with? I want to understand what I'm thinking and doing wrong here please.**

Can a table's Foreign-Key link to more than one table (Like my PageId in ContentColumn table) ?
To me how I have it makes sense as you can just have whichever page id in the Page Id table linking the `ContentCol` to each page.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Is your question if you can use the Primary Key of table pages in multiple other tables? If so, yes.

Comment: My question is what is wrong with my first design (without pages table) and if the PageId in ContentColumn table can be used to identify which table it belongs to. Btw I edited my question to add that clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to offer some point in your database design.

**First of all**: A foreign key constraint always references one target table.

So you can not merge two F.Ks in one column. (except you do not want to use DBMS constraints and handle this constraint in code, I do not recommend this)

**Secondly**: Your second design (`Page` table) is better than first design. You can handle the first design weakness with having `Page` table and using it's F.K into `ContentColumns`. Then you should use `Page` P.K as F.K into `ServicePage` and `AboutPage`.

**Thirdly**: I recommend that you can merge `AboutPage` and `ServicePage` in one table and use another table to hold their types.

Your `ServicePage` and `AboutPage` seems very similar in columns. I recommend to use these tables instead of your `AboutPage`, `ServicePage` or `Page` tables:

- a `PageType` table: this table hold you page types as records (AboutPage, ServicePage and other page types maybe you have in the future)
- a `Page` table saves all of your pages. You have a one-to-many relationship between `PageType` and `Page`. You should use `PageType` P.K as F.K in `Page`.

Then you can use `Page` P.K as F.K in `ContentColumns`.

With this design you can define any page types at runtime and dynamically control them.

Comment: Thanks very much for your in depth answer Golamali. I've edited it over the weekend. I was just confused due to the nature of the CMS concepts. Your quick rule of an FK can only reference one table makes complete sense as in a one to many the fk will always be in the many side so can only reference the 1 side. I just gave those About and Service page common columns but they actually other columns with different data. Thanks again.